# Azure Data Factory Insert/Update two tables at the same time

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, insert-update, dataflow

I've got 2 tables with multiple attributes (A) and values (V):

Table1 = [A1, A2, A3, A4, V1, V2]
Table2 = [A1, A2, avg(V1), max(V2)]

Table2 is an aggregation of Table1. I want to take advantage of the same data flow to insert/update these two tables at the same time. This is the last part of my design.

[image]

If I have to insert a new value, in both tables I see the register. However, If I have to update a register the condition seems to be valid only for Table1, Table2 is always inserting the register. This is what I see when I try to update:

[image]

I have modified this part adding a new AlterRow2 after the aggregate to get the right answer, but it is not so clear why this aggregation seems to be able to check the condition in the first image.

[image]

I would appreciate If you a better suggestion to solve this task.

Comment: You don't need to split with a new branch to write 2 different insert & update policies to the same table. You can just define update & insert rules in the same Alter Row on the same branch. Data flow will write the output separately to each sink sequentially. We are adding parallel writes, but today you'll get better perf to keep it in the same stream or branch.

Comment: Hi Mark Thanks for your answer. I'm not so sure if I am following you. The same action must be performed in both tables. In my first image the AlterRow1 has the 2 conditions, they work perfectly for Table1, but after the aggregation step, Azure is always generating an insert for the table 2. That is why I had to create a new AlterRow2 following the aggregation, and repeating the same conditions. I have updated the post with the image of a Update Process.

Comment: Alter Row is simply just tagging rows based on your rule. Whatever actions you enable in the database sink will be taken on those matching rows. Insert is the default action. You would need to disable "Allow Insert" if you do not wish to insert rows to that sink.

Comment: Correct. But that is my problem. When the Alter Row has detected an Update, it seems that the Aggrupation changes the tag always to "Insert" (image 2). So in the end I'm getting the Table1 updated (that is correct), and the Table2 with a new register (when I was also waiting an update).